# Why do scipy.linalg's methods run slower on 9x9 matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I'm comparing runtimes for various ways to solve linear systems, and I've found an odd pattern. The solution methods I'm testing are `la.solve()`, `la.inv()`, and `la.lu_factor_solve()`.

```
import scipy.linalg as la
import numpy as np
from time import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = 20  # up to NxN matrix
T = 100  # run T times
inv_time, solve_time = [[] for _ in range(20)], [[] for _ in range(20)]
lu_factor_solve, lu_just_solve = [[] for _ in range(20)], [[] for _ in range(20)]
for _ in range(T):
    for n in range(1, N + 1):
        A = np.random.rand(n, n)
        b = np.random.rand(n, 1)
        np.dot(la.inv(A), b)  # the first time through is always slow,
        la.solve(A, b)        # so we run it once to get it out of the way
        start = time()
        np.dot(la.inv(A), b)
        end = time()
        inv_time[n - 1].append(end - start)

        start = time()
        la.solve(A, b)
        end = time()
        solve_time[n - 1].append(end - start)

        start = time()
        la.lu_solve(la.lu_factor(A), b)
        end = time()
        lu_factor_solve[n - 1].append(end - start)

        temp = la.lu_factor(A)
        start = time()
        la.lu_solve(temp, b)
        end = time()
        lu_just_solve[n - 1].append(end - start)
inv_time = np.mean(np.array(inv_time), axis=1)
solve_time = np.mean(np.array(solve_time), axis=1)
lu_factor_solve = np.mean(np.array(lu_factor_solve), axis=1)
lu_just_solve = np.mean(np.array(lu_just_solve), axis=1)
# do some plots
plt.plot(range(1, N + 1), inv_time, '-o', label='by inverse')
plt.plot(range(1, N + 1), solve_time, '-o', label='by la.solve()')
plt.plot(range(1, N + 1), lu_factor_solve, '-o', label='by lu factor solve')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.plot(range(1, N + 1), lu_just_solve, '-o', label='just la.lu_solve()')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

These are run on random matrices `A` and column vectors `b` produced by `A = np.random.rand(n, n)` and `b = np.random.rand(n, 1)` for values of `n` from 1 to 20. I've found that every time I run the program, it finds solutions to 9x9 matrices much slower than for matrices of other sizes, as pictured below. The red line shows the time required just to perform `la.lu_solve()`. Here is a graph of the results with `T = 1`:
[image: Graph of times with T=1]

And here are the results with `T = 100`:
[image: Graph of times with T=100]

Does this have to do with something inherent about 9x9 matrices, some optimization not available for this size of matrix, or something different?

Comment: Probably related to BLAS/LAPACK, which is heavily optimized for SIMD and Caching. So it is kind of intuitive, that there are some cases where some n+1 is solved much slower than some n, where n = 2^x. But this is just an intuition and analysis might be not easy.

Comment: And it gets weirder: it happens every time I run it, but if I run it 100 times and average the values I get a very normalized graph with not even a bump at n=9.

Comment: In this case you probably should show some code as benchmarking is hard too (damn caches).

Comment: @sascha Just added my code.

Comment: I have to admit that i'm too lazy to check this code right now, but: my first steps would be (1) introducing ```new A's, b's``` for every approach inside the loop. This will introduce variance, but maybe this changes caching-behaviour. (2) re-order those approaches and observe if something changes. Also ```the first time through is always slow...``` sounds scary, but i'm not able to understand what you are trying to do there.

Comment: The `mean` is meaningless; with this, you just measure how much the fastest possible time was delayed on average by other processes running on the machine. When doing performance measurements, you always want to look the _minimum_ of all runs.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer I changed `mean` to `min` and received similar results.

Comment: @sascha I added that line because I was getting a large spike at just the first run. Changing `mean` to `min` means I can remove that line.

Comment: I tried your code and _sometimes_ see random spikes anywhere between 5 and 20. This could be anything. Some recurring task running on the machine, the CPU waking up from sleep states, you name it.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer OK, go ahead and address that in your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @KyleRoth Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code examples with [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) (a small project of mine, essentially a wrapper around timeit) and found no such peculiarities. One *can* recognize the exhaustion of the level-1-cache though:

[image]

This is with NumPy 1.13.3 and SciPy 1.0.0rc1.

The reason that there are spikes in your code sample when only running the tests *once* is that they run so fast that small interferences with other parts of the machine can become significant. This could be anything from recurring tasks from the JS-engine in your browser to your CPUs waking up from deeper sleep states. The fact that you see those spikes at `n=9` is a coincidence. I myself can reproduce random spikes anywhere between 5 and 20 when only running the tests once.

---

Code to reproduce the plot:

```
import numpy
import perfplot
import scipy.linalg as la


def solve(data):
    A, b = data
    return la.solve(A, b)


def dot_inv(data):
    A, b = data
    return numpy.dot(la.inv(A), b)


def lu_solve(data):
    A, b = data
    return la.lu_solve(la.lu_factor(A), b)


perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: (numpy.random.rand(n, n), numpy.random.rand(n)),
    kernels=[solve, dot_inv, lu_solve],
    n_range=range(1, 40),
    )
```

Comment: With `T = 2` and taking `min` instead of `mean`, the spike at `n = 9` goes away. I think the cause is actually the same thing that causes the first run on `n = 1` to go much slower than the others. See the comments on my question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any slowdown at `n=9`.

Comment: @KyleRoth Just to let you know, If you are using SciPy version 19.1, we replaced the underlying solver to a refined iterative solver for increased precision. This also might cause some differences depending on the problem solution (early termination for some but more iterations for others). Now it is obvious that this slowed down things and we are enabling the fast solvers again in version 1.0 which Nico is already using.